# Remove duplicates, and then make a count of total remainings

Tags: r

In the `Planes` dataframe, there are a lot of duplicates if we look at the columns `manufactor` and `model`
I wrote this code to see how much we have of the duplicats

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

dupl<- planes %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>% 
  summarise(duplicates=n())
```

If one would make a count of all the planes for each manufactor, some manufactor will have a lot of planes because they have duplicates. I want to remove the duplicates, so that each manufactor only has 1 of each model, and the count all planes for each manufactor (after removing duplicates)

This is where I am stuck. So basically, I want to find out how many manyfactures has more than 50 planes once we have cleaned up the duplicates

I tried doing so that each manufactor has only 1 plane of each model like this (Not sure if this is the right way to go though)

```
duplRemove<- dupl%>% 
   group_by(manufacturer, model, duplicates) %>% 
   mutate(RemovDupl = duplicates-duplicates+1)
```

Now how can I count the `RemoveDupl` for each manufactor? So for example, `AIRBUS` should show 14 planes (from what I can count with my own eyes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can double count, first by manufacturer and model, then by manufacturer:

```
library(dplyr)

planes %>% 
  count(manufacturer, model) %>%
  count(manufacturer)

# A tibble: 35 x 2
   manufacturer               n
   <chr>                  <int>
 1 AGUSTA SPA                 1
 2 AIRBUS                    14
 3 AIRBUS INDUSTRIE          13
 4 AMERICAN AIRCRAFT INC      1
 5 AVIAT AIRCRAFT INC         1
 6 AVIONS MARCEL DASSAULT     1
 7 BARKER JACK L              1
 8 BEECH                      2
 9 BELL                       2
10 BOEING                    65
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates in each group, one way would be to select only one row in each group. For example, here we select the 1st row in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

planes %>%  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>% slice(1L)
```

So if we count the `manufacturer` after selecting 1st row in each group, we get.

```
planes %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>% 
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(manufacturer)

# A tibble: 35 x 2
#   manufacturer               n
#   <chr>                  <int>
# 1 AGUSTA SPA                 1
# 2 AIRBUS                    14
# 3 AIRBUS INDUSTRIE          13
# 4 AMERICAN AIRCRAFT INC      1
# 5 AVIAT AIRCRAFT INC         1
# 6 AVIONS MARCEL DASSAULT     1
# 7 BARKER JACK L              1
# 8 BEECH                      2
# 9 BELL                       2
#10 BOEING                    65
# … with 25 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
rowSums(table(planes[c('manufacturer', 'model')])>0)
```